# Number 0 equal false in javascript, how to fix my code

Tags: angularjs, filter

I practiced sample code from book `Pro AngularJS` as below:

I tested there is a bug here if day `index` is `0`, for example, today is Sunday, so `now.GetDay()` return `0`. Then the view would think `0` is `false`, display `unknown` and not read day variable and followed filter process.

I want to ask what's the best/graceful way to fix this problem, to make sure Sunday case can works properly.

A method I thought is let `Module Value - days.today = nowValue.getDay() + 1`, so avoid `0` case, then in filter, minus 1 when using for `index` to read array.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Demo</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("exampleApp", []);
        myApp.controller("dayCtrl", function ($scope,days) {
            $scope.day = days.today;
        });
        myApp.controller("tomorrowCtrl", function ($scope, days) {
            $scope.day = days.tomorrow;
        });
        myApp.directive("highlight", function ($filter) {
            var dayFilter = $filter("dayName");
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                if (dayFilter(scope.day) == attrs["highlight"]) {
                    element.css("color", "red");
                }
            }
        });
        myApp.filter("dayName", function () {
            var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
            return function (input) {
                return angular.isNumber(input) ?  dayNames[input] : input;
            };
        });
        var now= new Date();
        myApp.value("nowValue", now);
        myApp.service("days", function (nowValue) {
            this.today = nowValue.getDay();
            this.tomorrow = (this.today + 1) ;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>AngularJS App</h3>
    </div>
    <h4 ng-controller="dayCtrl" highlight="Saturday">
        Today is {{day || "(unknown)" | dayName}}
    </h4>
    <h4 ng-controller="tomorrowCtrl">
        Tomorrow is {{day || "(unknown)" | dayName}}
    </h4>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: given a day index as returned by `getDay()`, get the day name from the array by this index, and then if the result is false show `unknown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the implementation of the filter is the problem here, because of the following line

```
{{day || "(unknown)" | dayName}}
```

here, when day is 0, it is a 'falsy' value and so, the "||" operator returns the second expression which is "(unknown)"
The responsibility of finding name of the day, if should lie in the filter then, I'd suggest you to write your filter as :

```
myApp.filter("dayName", function () {
    var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    return function (input) {
        // you don't have to check if it is a number, 
        // if you don't pass a valid value, undefined is returned anyways
        var dayName = dayNames[input] || "(unknown)";
    };
});
```

and you can use this filter just with 
    {{day | dayname}}

One important take away would be, don't distribute one responsibility in multiple places, if name of the day is responsibility of the filter, finding the default name should be too. This result in single maintenance point for bug fix, adding features and new changes.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
myApp.filter("dayName", function () {
    var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    return function (input) {
        input = (input > 6) ? 0 : input;
        return angular.isNumber(input) ?  dayNames[input] : input;
    };
});
```